An 'Invalid or illegal selector' error during Karate Appium execution. However, the same code works in the desktop browser
@home
  Scenario: Extract Subheadings using XPath
   Given driver baseUrl
    And delay(3000)
    * waitFor("//div[@class='ca23_home_heading']")
    * def subheadings = locateAll("//div[@class='ca23_home_heading']")
    * print 'subheading element:: ',subheadings
  * def texts = []
  * karate.forEach(subheadings, function(element){ karate.appendTo(texts, element.text) })
  * print 'texts in ui',texts

I am using the Karate UI framework for PWA application automation. The code works when I execute the automation in a desktop browser. However, the same code fails when I execute the scenario on a mobile device. On mobile, the browser launches, and execution proceeds until the line
def texts = []

It fails at the line
karate.forEach(subheadings, function(element) { karate.appendTo(texts, element.text) })

due to the following exception:
* karate.forEach(subheadings, function(element){ karate.appendTo(texts, element.text) })
js failed:
>>>>
01: karate.forEach(subheadings, function(element){ karate.appendTo(texts, element.text) })
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: locator failed twice: {"status":32,"value":{"message":"invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified\n  (Session info: chrome=115.0.5790.138)"},"sessionId":"558c7347-0a2e-48c4-9080-3728208c50b8"}
- com.intuit.karate.driver.WebDriver.elementId(WebDriver.java:217)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.appium.AppiumDriver.text(AppiumDriver.java:146)
- com.intuit.karate.driver.DriverElement.getText(DriverElement.java:277)
- <js>.:anonymous(Unnamed:1)


karate for mobile (via appium) is somewhat experimental. so do consider contributing code or look for another alternative
